# Firebase user not showing up in Auth User Console - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

My users are created successfully.

I can verify the user is created sucesfully because I can sign in with the credentials.

However, they are not showing up the in the user console.

[image: Firebase Console]

[image]

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            
            if error != nil {
            
                self.handleError(errorCode: AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code)!)

            } else {
              
                print("User Created Succesfully")
           
            }
        }
```

I dont know why they are not showing.

Could it be an issue with cocoa pods or firebase versions in Podfile? I already tried updating.

Comment: After creating the user, have you tried signing in with the received auth credentials?

Comment: yes, I have tried signing in with the credentials and it signs in successfully but the user is still not created.

Comment: @husharoonie - did you figure it out. its a bounty question.  bounty will end within minutes